# Issues converting string to double?

Tags: java

Trying to read in input as a string then convert it to double to calculate grossPay, I am getting an error that says cannot convert string to double.

```
public class EmployeeTest
{   
public static void main(String args[])
{

    String workerName;
    String hoursWorked;
    String hourlyPay;
    String grossPay;

    String isQuit;
    String message;

    workerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name");

    while(!workerName.equals("QUIT"))
    {

        hourlyPay = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hourly pay");
        hoursWorked = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours worked");
        grossPay = Double.parseDouble(hourlyPay)*Double.parseDouble(hoursWorked);


        Employee a1 = new Employee(workerName, hoursWorked, hourlyPay, grossPay);
```

Comment: Are the variables hourlyPay and hoursWorked initialized?

Comment: they are supposed to be read in using the JOptionPane as strings, I am then supposed to use those string to calculate the gross pay

Comment: add some checks like this: `if(hourlyPay != null && !hourlyPay.isEmpty() && hoursWorked != null && !hoursWork.isEmpty()) { }` This makes sure the variables are not null or empty (so they could be parsed). Maybe that will resolve the error, at some print calls to confirm this issue

Answer (score 1):

The error should actually be "cannot convert from double to String", because `grossPay` is of type `String`. To convert a `double` to a `String`, you can use `String#valueOf(double)`, but a better solution is to change the type of the variable to `double`:

```
double grossPay;
```

The other variables should also have their types changed to reflect their values:

```
int hoursWorked;
double hourlyPay;
```

Note that this requires changing the constructor of `Employee` to use the correct types.

Comment: The Q says " cannot convert string to double", and you answer the reverse problem??

Comment: @laune this answer is the correct way of doing it, please show us your exception with its (partial) trace. It might help us finding the issue

Comment: There's no need to to use `String.valueOf`, just changing the type of `grossPay` should be fine :)

Comment: @codequestioneer I was merely pointing out an obvious incompatibility, which manouti (thanks!) has edited into his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be:

```
Double grossPay;
```

Comment: You should convert String grossPay to Double grossPay. String str = "1234";
  Double str1 = Double.parseDouble(str) * Double.parseDouble(str);